# CKEDITOR opening in DOJO dialog in CKeditor changing font and size show error?

Tags: javascript, dojo, ckeditor

I have faced one issue like below screenshots.

In Ckeditor changing font size and Font it will show error like Webpage not displayed?

I am using version:'3.5.2' ckeditor and below bug some times comes not every time.
And I am using in a web based application.

[image]

[image]

I am using ckeditor in dojo dialog.
When I open color dialog in ckeditor more color option in ckeditor background going to fade by iframe. Next time when again open color dialog double iframe is coming. How to destroy color dialog in ckeditor?

Comment: You probably get better responses when you retag it to javascript instead of java. And there are no screenshots (well, I can't see them...).

Comment: 1) update CKEditor version (or at least write which one do you use), 2) check JS console, 3) check if your code modifies `document.domain`, 4) tell us from which domain CKEditor files are loaded.